# Executing an executable with GTK2 requirement on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: executable

I am trying to run this program (https://www.scarabee-software.net/en/siren.html) on Ubuntu 18.04 and it won't start.

> Requirements Windows : XP minimum GNU/Linux : GTK2 mandatory
>
> Installation No installation needed, unzip and run

I tried `sudo apt-get install gtk2.0`, reboot, but still does not start.

Do I need to do something else?

Comment: The instructions are "No installation needed, unzip and run". So what difficulty did you face?

Comment: The author post an answer on his forum here "http://scarabee-software.net/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=1517#p1517").  Want to thank Norbert for being so helpful.  I didn't try his solution but it should work as he has demonstrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested on clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
Simply downloaded and extracted the software

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://www.scarabee-software.net/download/Siren_314_gnulinux_amd64.tar.gz
tar -xf Siren_314_gnulinux_amd64.tar.gz
cd Siren
./siren
```

Then got the following error about missed obsolete *libng12*:

> $ ./siren
>      ./siren: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So we need to download and install this library manually from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

then it comlains about missed `canberra-gtk-module`

> $ ./siren
>   Gtk-Message: 19:16:12.501: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

so we need to install it

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module
```

and finally

```
$ ./siren
```

[image: Siren on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS]

---

**Note:** Siren will work normally on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and 16.04 LTS as they have *libpng12* preinstalled.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort in answering my question.  I got an answer from the author with solution like your and it works.  Thanks again